# Calculate standard deviation and mean of column for each row excluding the row for which mean is calculated

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a certain column in DataFrame so that the mean and standard deviation  for each row is calculated excluding the value of the row for which it's calculated.

I know I can iterate each row by index, dropping each row by index in every iteration, and then calculate the mean. I wonder if there's a more efficient way of doing it.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'marks':[10,20,30,10]})
```

I have one solution which works only when no element is repeating but in my data, we have 10 repeating two times so my approach doesn't work.

Approach:

```
data['marks'].apply(lambda x: data.loc[data.marks!= x, 'marks'].mean())

data['marks'].apply(lambda x: np.std(data.loc[data.marks!= x, 'marks']))
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: For mean it's just `(df['mask'].sum() - df['mask'])/(len(df)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

The average is the sum of all values divided the amount of elements, therefore to exclude considering the own row's value we can try:

```
def mean_except_self(s):
    '''
    calculate mean of the series except the value of each row

    '''
    if len(s) <= 1: return np.nan
    return (s.sum() - s) / (len(s) - 1)

data['new_average'] = mean_except_self(data['marks'])
data['new_std'] = mean_except_self(data['marks']**2) - data['new_average']**2
```

Comment: what about std deviation?

Comment: @AbhinavKhandelwal std can be taken as `mean(x**2) - mean(x)**2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang No, I don't think it will work in my case as I need to leave one out for caluclation.

Comment: @AbhinavKhandelwal Yes it does. the `mean` here is the function given in this answer, not the usual `mean` :-).

Comment: I basically need help in getting standard deviation

Comment: @QuangHoang can you please help to provide full command which you are talking about... I guess I got confused

Comment: See the updated answer. @CeliusStinger hop you don't mind the edit.

Comment: Thanks, no issue at all. Sadly I'm on the streets and can't contribute much.

Comment: It is not giving the right answer. The standard deviation value is coming wrong. For the first row it should be 1.118 but it is coming 1.25

Comment: @QuangHoang any leads for this issue?

Comment: @AbhinavKhandelwal I think the answers provides a clear path to solving the problem with the std. Consider making a formula that calculates the std in the same manner the average was calculated.